# Symfony2: How to disable form field on edit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

How can I disable form's name field, if the name of the object is, for example, 'Default'? So users cannot change name for 'Default' object, but can for any other object?

This is what I already have:

*ObjectType*

```
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name','text', array('required' => true))
        ->add('description', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
            Object::TYPE_PUBLIC => 'Public',
            Object::TYPE_PRIVATE => 'Private',
        ),
        ));
}
```

*Edit action*

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="edit_object")
 * @ParamConverter("object", class="ObjectBundle:Object")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction(Object $object, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObjectType(), $object, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('edit_object',['id' => $object->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('@Object/Object/list.html.twig', array(
            'object' => $object));
    }
    return array('collection'=>$collection, 'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Comment: In the ObjectType, usually the quickest way is to check if the underlying entity has an id or not, and remove the field if it does; e.g: `if (null !== $builder->getData()->getId()) { $builder->remove('name'); }`

Answer (score 3):

A real simple way is to pass a value to the constructor of the form with a flag on if you are editing.  So your form type would be:

```
class ObjectType extends AbstractType
{
    private $isEdit;

    public function __construct($isEdit = false)
    {
        $this->isEdit = $isEdit;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
            ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
                Object::TYPE_PUBLIC => 'Public',
                Object::TYPE_PRIVATE => 'Private',
            ),
        ));

        if (!$editMode) {
            $builder->add('name','text', array('required' => true));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function editAction(Object $object, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObjectType($isEdit = true), $object, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('edit_object',['id' => $object->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
    //...
}
```

For the `createForm` on creating a new, you could just pass `new ObjectType()` and leave off the parameter since it is defaulted to `false` in this case.

---

Another method would be to build your form based on the entity you are passing to it, aka [FormEvents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).  If it already contains a value for the id, you could simply not add the name field to the form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('description', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
            Object::TYPE_PUBLIC => 'Public',
            Object::TYPE_PRIVATE => 'Private',
        ),
    ));

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $object= $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$object || null === $object->getId()) {
            $form->add('name','text', array('required' => true));
        }
    });
```

The exact use case I just gave is [specifically documented in Symfony's book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class)

Comment: The drawback of the first approach is that this will not work anymore with Symfony 3.0 where you cannot instantiate form type classes when building your forms (passing constructor arguments will only work when registering form types as a service). The second approach (using form events) is more sane.

Comment: Very interesting - and registering it as a service means you're not going to be passing dynamic values to the constructor anyway.  I've taken a 3rd approach in the past where I register a key in `configureOptions`/`setDefaultOptions` and then pass my value into the `array $options` when creating the form - will that still work in Symfony3?

Comment: Yes, this will still work. Options should be used to configure things that are specific to a particular form (like choices in the entity type) while the constructor should be used to pass general dependencies (for example, the entity type retrieves the `ManagerRegistry` and the `PropertyAccessor` in the constructor).

Comment: To be clear: `setDefaultOptions()` will not work anymore (it has been removed as well as the `OptionsResolverInterface)`, but its replacement, the `configureOptions()` method, does of course.

Comment: Right - I was just mentioning both just because they were both valid in Symfony 2.x (I know `configureOptions` was introduced in 2.7) - good additional info.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't meant to be mean here. I simply notice that people seem to have some trouble updating their forms to Symfony 3 and wanted to mention some pitfalls that might occur to you when using certain approaches in Symfony 2 nowadays and then upgrading in the future.